# prevent twig from escaping form field values

Tags: symfony, escaping, twig

My form field's values get escaped after a save (using doctrine) to the database, on reload they display like this: Title\'s any ideas on how can prevent symfony/twig from escaping form field values?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Twig Documentation

```
{{ var|raw }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Answer (score -1):

This sounds more like PHP's "[magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)" than anything Symfony2 or Twig would do. (But it's hard to tell when you're not showing any code. ;)) See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) for how to disable it.

Comment: Correct, but should've been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Maerlyn Please elaborate. I've answered the question, so why should it have been a comment? Because the question itself is misguided(?) in its assumption of the cause? (Wouldn't that be better handled by editing the question?)